# Dynamically change JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am fetching the data values from the database successfully. I have also stored them into a `String[]` array. I need to load the String array as the items of the `JComboBox` in response to key actionperformed. How can I reload the items of the `JComboBox` whenever a key is pressed as the fetched values depend on the key pressed. Rather simply, I need to dynamically refresh the `JComboBox` items.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>( yourStringArray );
comboBox.setModel( model );
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but can you please  post a code to illustrarte this. it will be very helpfull.  I am not sure of what to write in the DefaultComboBoxModel class.

Comment: That is the code. You don't write anything in the DefaultComboBoxModel class. You just create the model using your array of strings and then add the model to the combo box.

Answer (score 7):

You have a couple of options. You can use `removeAllItems()` (or one of the other remove methods) and `addItem(Object anObject)` to manipulate the selectable objects. Or you could implement a `ComboBoxModel`and allow it to serve up data from your array.

Answer (score 7):

This is the demo for illustrating default combo box model

```
public class ComboPanel extends JPanel {

    JComboBox jcbo;
    // this is constructor
    public ComboPanel(ArrayList<String> items) {
        jcbo = new JComboBox();
        // getting exiting combo box model
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) jcbo.getModel();
        // removing old data
        model.removeAllElements();

        for (String item : items) {
            model.addElement(item);
        }

        // setting model with new data
        jcbo.setModel(model);
        // adding combobox to panel
        this.add(jcbo);    
    }
}
```

I hope this will help little :)