# Transfer Items from One JComboBox to another JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Hi I'm trying to transfer one object from one combobox to another and vice versa.
To accomplish this,
I use actionListeners or ItemListeners, to no luck that they dont answer my problems, or maybe there's just something wrong in my implementation.

Assuming we have to comboboxes, combobox1 and combobox2.
Basically, 
1. I first add the selected item to another combobox (combobox2)
2. I remove the selected item on the first combobox (combobox1)

When trying to debug this, i found out that everytime i am on the step of removing items, the listener of the other combobox fires, which does the same steps as above. This results into a loop, that just deletes the item, and places it back to the original combobox.

When using the ItemListener, with the proper if conditions of being selected or not, it throws a bigger error. Guys please help me..

*on edit mode/currently making an SSCE

Comment: all changes to JComboBox should be done in its model, search here for DefaultComboBoxModel, better for MutableComboBoxModel

Comment: question in this form isn't answerable here, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JComboBox in local variable, maybe to use GridLayout instead of MigLayout for code in SSCCE/MCVE form here

Comment: Not an answer but a piece of advice: why don't use two `JList`s instead of combo boxes? You can easy transfer items between lists' models.

Comment: but cant we use jcombobox instead of list? im using combobox to save space.

Comment: To save space, the suggestion of @dic19 can be done in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620295/dynamically-change-jcombobox/4620374#4620374), as suggested by sir mKorbel.
It did the trick, setting the model via setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel model) method doesnt trigger the ActionListener when it tries to add the contents of the model passed, versus the addItem(Object obj) method that fires the ActionListener causing the havoc that i described on my question above.

Thanks guys, and i learned about a new thing called DefaultComboBoxModels!

Answer (score 1):

```
jComboBox12.removeAllItems();
for (int t = 0; t < jComboBox11.getItemCount(); t++) 
{
 jComboBox12.addItem(jComboBox11.getItemAt(t));
}
```

Comment: code-only answers are not so helpful. Please explain.

Comment: this isn't dynamic. you just remove all and added them back again. and this would fire the same problem mentioned above